# Is there a way to write a macro to do perfect forwarding using only the variable name (i.e. a FWD(t) which is equivalent to std::forward<T>(t))?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, decltype, perfect-forwarding

I have something like (let's say):

```
template <typename Collection, typename Item>
void foo_collection(Collection&& c, Item && i) {
    foo(std::forward<Collection>(c), std::forward<Item>(i));
}
```

I don't like the fact that `std::forward<Collection>(c)` is so long. I'd like to do this, instead:

```
template <typename Collection, typename Item>
void foo_collection(Collection&& c, Item&& i) {
    foo(FWD(c), FWD(i));
}
```

I am thinking there must be a way to do this using `decltype`. I figure, given the `decltype(i)`, if I remove all references and consts from it, I'll get `Item`, and then it should work:

```
#define FWD(v) \
    std::forward< \
        typename std::remove_const<\
        typename std::remove_reference<\
        decltype(v)>::type>::type>(v)
```

However, this [doesn't work](https://ideone.com/KPzObm):

```
void foo(int& a) { cout << "ref" << endl; }
void foo(const int& a) { cout << "cref" << endl; }

template <typename T>
void call_foo(T&& t) { foo(FWD(t)); }

int main() {
    int a = 10;
    foo(10);      // 1) prints cref
    foo(a);       // 2) prints ref
    call_foo(10); // 3) prints cref
    call_foo(a);  // 4) prints cref
    return 0;
}
```

Why does `4` call the `cref` overload, and not the `ref` overload?

I tried `#define FWD(a) std::forward<decltype(a)>(a)`, and in this example it [*did* work](https://ideone.com/s5qigW). However, I am guessing that it won't work in all cases. Is that the case, and if so, which cases won't it work in?

Finally, if the latter approach doesn't work, is there any way to write this macro in a way that works?

Comment: *"I am guessing that it won't work in all cases*" What makes you say this?

Comment: @0x499602D2: If the parameter is `T&& t`, doesn't `decltype(t)` give you `T&&`, while you're supposed to pass `T` to std::forward?

Comment: @Claudiu, the outcome is the same `std::forward<T&&>(t)` equal `std::forward<T>(t)`, isn't it? It isn't in the standard because they don't like macros at all

Comment: @WorldSEnder: It ends up being misleading, e.g. `FWD(v)` would work but `FWD((v))` wouldn't (since `decltype(v) != decltype((v))`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#define FWD(a) std::forward<decltype(a)>(a)
```

will work.  So long as `a` is the name of a variable, `decltype(a)` is the type it was declared as, which is what you are supposed to pass to `forward` as its type parameter.

If you pass in an expression, things could get strange.  I cannot think up a case where it fails, however.

Naturally this doesn't work for some more advanced uses of `forward`.

Comment: If the parameter is `T&& t`, doesn't `decltype(t)` give you `T&&`, while you're supposed to pass `T` to std::forward? Also what are the more advanced usages of `forward` where this won't work?

Comment: @Claudiu Passing `T&&` works with `std::forward`, and acts like `T`.  The more advanced uses of `std::forward` don't tie the current variable's declaration to how it should be forwarded, for example a call-once lambda that forwards something it captured by reference.

Answer (score 2):

The approach

```
#define FWD(a) std::forward<decltype(a)>(a)
```

actually works as can seen [here](http://ideone.com/ZKHegx)

```
void foo(int& a) { cout << "lref" << endl; }
void foo(const int& a) { cout << "cref" << endl; }
void foo(int&& a) { cout << "rref" << endl; }

template <typename T>
void call_foo(T&& t) { foo(FWD(t)); }


int main() {
    int a = 10;
    call_foo(10); // 3) prints rref
    call_foo(a);  // 4) prints lref
    return 0;
}
```